# How can I test Page reference in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex

Please I am newbie to salesforce and I want to make unit testing forthis method:

```
public PageReference method1(){
        PageReference p = new PageReference ('/hello');
        p.setRedirect(true);
        p.getParameters().put('id',id);
         if(code!=null){
            p.getParameters().put('ld',ld);
            p.getParameters().put('ph',ph);
         }
        return p;
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You really need to provide your whole apex class and visualforce page to ensure that someone answering your question can do so, but here's a generic stab at it:

```
static testMethod void testMyMethod(){
  test.StartTest();
    PageReference testPage = Page.pageName;
    test.setCurrentPage(testPage);

    className controller = new className();
    controller.code = 'testcode';
    controller.id = 'testid';
    controller.ld = 'testld';
    controller.ph = 'testph';
    PageReference pr = controller.method1();
    system.assert( pr.getParameters().get('id') == 'testid' );
    system.assert( pr.getParameters().get('ld') == 'testld' );
    system.assert( pr.getParameters().get('ph') == 'testph' );
  test.StopTest();
}
```